# Append Words from different arrays to div

Tags: jquery

this might be easy but I cannot see the forest because of trees.
I have several arrays of words and fade-in-times.

**This should happen:**
On Start words from array PartA are added to the div with respect of each individual time. For this I use setTimeout().

**Not working.** 
If a User clicks on a link added from partA Words from array partB (or partN) should be append to the div as well.  How can I pass in the current array of interest to `function buildString(what)` ?

This is where I hang

```js
  
// WORDS!
partA = [ 
        ["Hello", 300],
        ["my", 300],
        ["name", 300],
        ["<a href='#' class='partB' >is</a>", 600],
        [".", 300],
    ];

PartB = [
        ["Good", 300],
        ["Bye", 300]
    ];

// Function to iterate over array
var i = 1;
function buildString(what) {
   $('div').append(partA[i-1][0]+' ');
   if(i > partA.length-1) return;
   i++;
   window.setTimeout(buildString, partA[i-1][1]);
}

// Bind click on link to continue with different array
$('a.partB').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // Continue with part B
  // Not working
 buildString(partB);
})

// Begin with first array
buildString(partA);
```

```css
#div {
    font-size: 50pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin:2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

**EDIT:**
When using what in my setTimeout function and injecting the array:

```
function buildString(what) {
   $('div').append(what[i-1][0]+' ');
   if(i > what.length-1) return;
   i++;
   window.setTimeout(buildString(what), what[i-1][1]);
}
```

The words do not get appended each after another but the whole sting is added.

https://jsfiddle.net/telemark/yxkazn1k/2/

Comment: You're not using "what" in your function

Comment: Yes because it´s not working ;) If I´m injecting the array only the first word is added. I thought asking that way is easier as starting point ...

Comment: No I mean... Your function has a param "what" but you only use "partA"

Comment: Hi John, I´ve edited my question, If I´m using what in setTimeout() the words do not get appended anymore. That´s why I thought the example before was a bit better because people can see what should happen ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your `buildString` function you did not use you parameter.
2. I think that using an internal index in sted of a global i would be much better.
3. Third and most imporant if you create dinamically an element (like you did with your link) you cannot bind an event of an element that dows not already exist.

What you can do is to `bind the click event to an anchestor` like I did in the example. Basically you bind the click event to every descendant of document of the class `a.partB`

```js
  
// WORDS!
partA = [ 
        ["Hello", 300],
        ["my", 300],
        ["name", 300],
        ["<a href='#' class='partB' >is</a>", 600],
        [".", 300],
    ];

partB = [
        ["Good", 300],
        ["Bye", 300]
    ];

// Function to iterate over array
function buildString(part, index) {
   console.log('part');
   console.log(part);
   console.log('with index ' + index);
   console.log(part[index]);
   $('div').append(part[index][0]+' ');
   if(index == part.length-1) return;
   index++;
   window.setTimeout(buildString, part[index-1][1], part, index);
}

$(document).on('click', 'a.partB', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // Continue with part B
  console.log('here we go B');
 buildString(partB, 0);
});

buildString(partA, 0);
```

```css
#div {
    font-size: 50pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin:2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hallleron/4x93qx1x/

I use a for loop for execution and add your timeout values each cicle:

```
var box = $('div');
var before;
function buildString(array) {
    before = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    appendToBox(array[i]);
   }
}

function appendToBox(obj){
    setTimeout(function(){
        box.append(obj[0] + ' ');
    }, obj[1] + before);
    before += obj[1];
}
```

Using this method ensures that every timeout value can be executed properly.

**EDIT:**

And you can pass as many Arrays as you want to you buildString(array) function.

Comment: Also a great way! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Working fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/L6yjxnav/)

```
  // Function to iterate over array -> buildString(partA);
  function buildString(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      setTimeout($('#div').append(item[0] + ' '), item[1]);
    })
  }
  $(document).on('click', 'a.partB', function(e) {
    buildString(partB);
  });
  buildString(partA);
```